# Add to an arraylist from different arraylist index

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, listbox

I have two array lists one in which I read in values from an XML, and then I add a specific tag to a listbox. From the listbox I transfer over the tag to another listbox, but the problem I am having is when trying to get the values of the selected item in the listbox in array1 to move over to array2.
How can I do this and make sure all things saved in the current index of arraylist1 move to arraylist2?

//Initialisation

```
    int moduleCount = 0;
    bool isFull = false;
    ArrayList chosen= new ArrayList();
    ArrayList module = new ArrayList();
    String name;
    String code;
    String info;
    String semester;
    String tSlot;
    String lSlot;
    String preReq;
    string xmlDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createBox();
        //List<Array> a=new List<Array>();            

        // Console.WriteLine(module.ToString());
       // getXML();
    }

    private void createBox()
    {
        String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\XML.xml");
        textReader.Read();
        XmlNodeType type;

        while (textReader.Read())
        {
            textReader.MoveToElement();
            type = textReader.NodeType;
            if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (textReader.Name == "Code")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    code = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(code);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Name")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    name = textReader.Value;
                    //selectionBox.Items.Add(name);
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Semester")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    semester = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(semester);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Prerequisite")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    preReq = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(code);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "LectureSlot")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    lSlot = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(lSlot);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "TutorialSlot")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    tSlot = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(tSlot);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Info")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    info = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(info);
                    module.Add(new Modules(code, name, semester, tSlot, lSlot, info, preReq));
                }
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(module);
        }
        foreach (object o in module)
        {
            Modules m = (Modules)o;
            //String hold = m.mName;
            selectionBox.Items.Add(m.mName);
        }
        textReader.Close();
```

//button event handler to move from one listbox to the other

```
if (selectionBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            chosenBox.Items.Add(selectionBox.SelectedItem);
            selectionBox.Items.Remove(selectionBox.SelectedItem);
            chosen.Add(selectionBox.SelectedItem);
            errorLabel.Text = "";
            moduleCount++;
            if (moduleCount >= 8)
            {
                isFull = true;
                errorLabel.Text = "You have selected 8 Modules please fill the fields and submit";
                selectionBox.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Please select a module";
        }

        numberChosen.Text = String.Format(moduleCount.ToString());
```

//Write to XML

```
 foreach (object o in chosen)
            {
                Modules m = (Modules)o;
                if (m.mPreReq != "None")
                {   
                    MessageBox.Show("You must chose module " + m.mPreReq);
                    //errorLabel.Text = "You must chose module " + m.mPreReq;
                    errorLabel.Text = "There is a prereq course";
                    req = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli Well the problem is the other values which are saved in modules so the 'code' the 'info' the 'semester' etc don't go to the second array list when I click on the button.

Comment: Ok so you've selected all of them and you want to move them with one click? In that case you'd have to use the SelectedItems property which is a collection and not the SelectedItem property which is just a single object

Comment: @SpaceghostAli No I just want to move one value in the listbox to the other listbox and when I do that I want to move all properties tags that are associated with the selected item thats moved, so the 'id','code' etc to the second arraylist.

Comment: I assume you mean the chosen ArrayList? You don't have any code in the button's event handler that attempts to read from the modules ArrayList and move that data to another list though so naturally nothing will be moved.

Comment: @SpaceghostAli Yes I mean the chosen ArrayList. Yeah sadly I dont have any code because I was trying the following but it wouldn't work: chosen.Add(module.Get(index));

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems like you need to relate m.mName that you add to selectionBox to the actual Module you added to the module ArrayList so that you can add the members of that module to the chosen ArrayList later on. Something like:

```
if (selectionBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    chosenBox.Items.Add(selectionBox.SelectedItem);
    selectionBox.Items.Remove(selectionBox.SelectedItem);

    foreach (Module m in module)
    {
        if (m.Name.Equals(selectionBox.SelectedItem)
        {
            chosen.Add(m.Info);
            chosen.Add(m.Code);
            ...
            break;
        }
     }

     errorLabel.Text = "";
     moduleCount++;
     if (moduleCount >= 8)
     {
         isFull = true;
         errorLabel.Text = "You have selected 8 Modules please fill the fields and submit";
         selectionBox.Enabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
        errorLabel.Text = "Please select a module";
     }
 }

 numberChosen.Text = String.Format(moduleCount.ToString());
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work I have tried experimenting by adding consolewritelines and am trying to get the values stored in the list and add them to an XML

Comment: Where specifically is it failing? Do you get an exception, is there Module not found?

Comment: It fails when I press submit and then when trying to write to the XML it gets a null value for the condition. I will add the code above.

Comment: Have you confirmed that mPreReq and all the other members are set when you create an instance of a Module? You need to debug and get more specifics about what exactly isn't working right.

Comment: Yes I am sure because if I use the module ArrayList in the foreach then errors will flag, and say that there are req errors